# Save .msg in C# with Outlook Interop: Correctly display Special Characters (UTF-8)

Tags: c#, utf-8, outlook, interop, special-characters

My C# console app is reading recipients from a .csv file which is saved with the charset UTF-8 and contains special chars (chinese letters, ö, ä, etc.). Now generating .msg-files by creating a MailItem and after setting MailItemObject.To and MailItemObject.Body and using MailItemObject.SaveAs is working just fine but is not correctly displaying special characters.

The file in the windows explorer looks like this:
[image]

And the body just ignores the special char:

[image]

When reading/writing .csv files I am using a Streamwriter/Streamreader and can set the Encoding.UTF8 which also works fine.
This console app also generates .xlsx files from data read from .csv files and this also works just fine.

My code:

```cs
Outlook.MailItem oMsg = (Outlook.MailItem)oOL.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
oMsg.Subject = "Test";

string recipient = "";
foreach (string s in recipients)
{
    recipient += s;
    recipient += "; ";
}
oMsg.To = recipient;

string cc = "";
foreach (string s in incopy)
{
    cc += s;
    cc += "; ";
}
oMsg.CC = cc;

foreach (string s in stringcountries)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Directory.GetFiles(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\outputfiles\\excel", "*" + s + "*").Length; i++)
    {
        oMsg.Attachments.Add(Directory.GetFiles(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\outputfiles\\excel", "*" + s + "*")[i]);
    }
}

string body = "";
oMsg.Body = body;
oMsg.SaveAs(path + recipientnames[0] + ".msg");
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

EDIT: If I hardcode a special character like "ö" into the source code it displays correctly both in the filename and the mailbody. Does this help my problem? If so, can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: This is not about your problem, I just want to make you aware of String.Join. It joins multiple strings into one with a delimiter like this ```oMsg.To = String.Join(';', recipients)+"; ";```.

Comment: ^^ and also [Path.Combine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=net-5.0) ...

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._mailitem.saveas?view=outlook-pia#Microsoft_Office_Interop_Outlook__MailItem_SaveAs_System_String_System_Object_ can take `type` param as olMSGUnicode . Have you tried that?

Comment: I tried to set oMsg.SaveAs(path + recipientnames[0] + ".msg", Outlook.OlSaveAsType.olMSGUnicode); but sadly it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

By experience MailItem are saved in UTF-8 only if a special character is present in one of certain field, if not, the mailItem is saved in US-ASCII..

We used a workaround by adding an invisible special character at the end of the subject (alt + 0160 |  )

Comment: Why not simple save in the olMsgUnicode format?